# How to set the content of an element to value of its attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

This is just an exercise that I thought of while playing with jsFiddle.

Given elements with a data attribute:

`<div data-test-id="3214581">Loading...</div>
 <div data-test-id="6584634">Loading...</div>`

I want to set the text content to result of function with that ID, such that final DOM is:

`<div data-test-id="3214581">John, Smith</div>`

so far I was able to find the given element and but somehow can't refer to the element using `this` keyword to get its testId:

`$('div[data-test-id]').text(getPersonName($(this).data('testId')))`

getPersonName() returns "John, Smith"

I think it should be that simple, but haven't found a self-referencing example like this on stack or jQuery docs.

EDIT: Fixed element to show multiple divs, not just one. (i.e. the ID is not known and shouldn't be in selector). Fixed select to have single quotes around it.

Comment: Your expectation reflects a fundamental misunderstanding about [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: It would appear your selectors are incorrect.  The selector is a string: `$('div[data-test-id]`)`....

Comment: You can use the `each` function - `$(div[data-test-id]).each(function(){ $(this).text(getPersonName($(this).data('testId'))); });`

Comment: Can you include text of `getPersonName` at Question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is the context of the function.

If nothing specifies further, `this` is simply `window`.

What you want is to pass a callback to `$.text`, that will be bound to the selected DOM element:

```
$('div[data-test-id]').text(function(){
  // here this is your div
  return getPersonName($(this).data('testId'))
})
```

Comment: This is correct except you forgot the `return getPersonName`. The function should return the string and it will be placed in text(). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the `this` keyword won't help you to do this in the current context. You'll need to use jQuery's `each` to loop over the results of the `$(div[data-test-id])` query. Then, inside the callback given to each, the value of `this` will be bound to the DOM node.

```
// "this" in this scope is not the DOM element
$(div[data-test-id]).each(function() {
  // "this" inside this scope is bound to the DOM element
  $(this).text(getPersonName($(this).data('testId')));
});
```

Comment: Or .text() accepts a callback function that will be called for each matched element, so no need for .each().

Comment: this is true, if you have a function that returns something. @moonwave99 got it but he forgot the return keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I got curious as to how much longer a pure javascript translation would be compared to moonwave99's answer. Just in case someone is interested in this as well, here it is:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div[data-test-id]"),function(el){
    el.innerHTML=getPersonName(el.getAttribute("data-test-id"));
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6rox273/)

Comment: `.innerHTML = ` is very different from a `.text()` call.

Comment: `for (let el of document.querySelectorAll("div[data-test-id]")) el.textContent = getPersonName(el.dataset.testId);` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary use iteration methods; `.text()` iterates each element at selector , `this` is already current element within function of `.text(function(index, text){})`.

You can adjust `getPersonName` to signature of `.text()` which should allow you to use pattern

```
$("div[data-test-id]").text(getPersonName);
```

---

```js
var names = {
  3214581: "John, Smith",
  6584634: "Stack, Overflow"
}

function getPersonName(index, text) {      
  return names[$(this).data().testId]
}

$("div[data-test-id]").text(getPersonName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-test-id="3214581">Loading...</div>
<div data-test-id="6584634">Loading...</div>
```